# Chrome select input click event alternative (change doesn't do what I need)

Tags: javascript, html, select, click

I need to fire an event when a select option is selected (including reselected).  I was using click in ie/FF but I realized there is no click event for webkit browsers.  Change will not work for me since I need it when it is reselected as well.  Is there a way I can achieve this functionality or do I need to replace the select with some sort of combo widget?

Comment: You could use jQuery, its own click event implementation will abstract away browser differences for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one event that will get fired by all browsers on an option click. In IE an option click that doesn't change the select will fire no events at all. You can catch `change` on the select as well as `click` on the option in an attempt to get the event in any many cases as possible, but it won't be 100%.

If you have a drop-down where clicking an option has an effect even if it was already selected, what you have isn't really a select box. Selects are designed to choose one option from a list and if that's not what you want you shouldn't mark it up as a `<select>`. Try to shoehorn a bunch of actions or navigation into a select box and you'll face a wide range of usability and accessibility issues.

Instead, try a box full of buttons (for actions) or links (for navigation), which pops up when you click on an arrow-button. You can style it to look like a select if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using onmouseup, or onfocus.